# Working locally on an existing remote Laravel project linked with a database

Tags: php, laravel, database, amazon-ec2, backend

I have recently joined a project that uses AWS EC2 to deploy a frontend in NodeJS and a backend in Laravel linked to a phpMyAdmin database. My question is simple but I have not found the way to do it despite litteral hours of research.
How can I launch the backend locally and use the corresponding database?

I should add that the database seems to be automatically generated by the Laravel backend and it contains a folder of "mutations".
I am relatively new to php, VMs and Linux overall.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

This project is probably using mysql or mariadb as database engine.
You must install the engine and export all of data from server and import it in your local database.
If database is on server and you want to connect to that database, it depends on security mechanisms. You must expose the db engine's port in the server and changing your laravel config to use that host for database connection. But I don't recommend that!

If you just want to run backend for personal tests, just setup backend and database engine and run migrations. I can't help you with this step cause I don't know how are deploy operations in your team. If you provide more information, we can help better.